# Remove the max length restriction on the search boxes

Tags: feature-request, search, design

When searching, it is easy to hit the 140 character max length on the search box:

> [image]

But by removing the `maxlength` attribute, this can be bypassed, with the search still working perfectly:

> [image]

Also, the search box at the top of the page (as opposed to *on* a search page) has a **2**40 character limit:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I propose removing the `maxlength` attribute from both search boxes, as I see no  reason to restrict this.

Doing so allows for [longer searches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstackoverflow%5D+migrated%3Ano+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bc%5D+-%5Bcpp%5D+-%5Bjava%5D+-%5Bhaskell%5D+-%5Bc%23%5D+-%5Bjs%5D+-%5Bruby*%5D+-%5Bf%23%5D+-%5Bmemory%5D+-%5Bfortran%5D+-%5Bapplescript%5D+-%5Basp*%5D+-%5Bvalgrind%5D+-%5Bprolog%5D+-%5Bdelphi%5D+-%5Bvb*%5D+-%5Bassembly%5D+-%5Bexception%5D+-%5Brecursion%5D+-%5Bscala%5D+-%5Bhtml-agility-pack%5D+-%5Bgroovy%5D+-%5Bjq%5D+-%5B.net%5D+-%5Bcommon-lisp%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%5Bflash%5D+-%5Blua%5D+-%5Blinux%5D) with no consequence.

Comment: But but but you won't be able to _tweet_ your searches!

Comment: @Oded (I know it's a joke) The URL itself though, is more than 140 characters `;)`

Comment: @Oded Twitter automatically shortens URLs. BRO, DO YOU EVEN TWEET?!??

Comment: @BilltheLizard - What gave it away?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Hahaha, I also didn't know that, for the same reason as Oded.

Comment: didn´t know that i can do `not` search for tags

Comment: I imagine this has more to do with the processing power required to parse 240 characters, and the added selectivity-cost of such a query.

Comment: Bumping this with a bounty, I would really like this as well. It's a simple change of a value, unless there are pressing concerns this is an easy fix.

Comment: It became 240 :)

Comment: Can we get an update on this?

Answer (score 5):

Seconded. In the meantime, here are a few workarounds:

- Bookmarklet

> javascript:void($("input").removeAttr("maxLength"))

- Data Explorer Query

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/142621/questions-with-only-one-tag