# Too many tags in the search query stop the live activity-notification bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

I've been working for a long time with an occasionally updated search string to keep track of the tags I want to follow. This has already caused [problems with the searchbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187508/remove-the-max-length-restriction-on-the-search-boxes) but you can work around that by constructing the URL yourself.

However the problem I'm currently facing is that I'm losing the *"x questions with new activity"* live notification bar once you go past a certain amount of tags (20, I believe).

Up until yesterday I was working with a search query that consisted of 20 tags and it went flawlessly. Today I added 2 new ones and the live-updating stopped.

Consider these two tabs that got refreshed at the same time and then left there for some time:

[22 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+asp.net+or+asp.net-mvc+or+asp.net-mvc-4+or+java+or+linq+or+design-patterns+or+android+or+unit-testing+or+architecture+or+design+or+oop+or+software-engineering+or+log4net+or+algorithm+or+wpf+or+linqpad+or+visual-studio+or+visual-studio-2012+or+resharper+or+code-generation+c%23+or+code-generation+.net?sort=newest&pageSize=15)

> [image]

[5 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+c#+or+.net+or+asp.net-mvc-4+or+android?sort=newest&pageSize=15)

> [image]

Only the latter has the live-update notification.

So my question: is this intended behaviour? If it is then this is a feature request to allow us to specify more tags.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204316/too-many-tags-requested-search-limited-to-25-tags) indicates it is now limited to 35 criteria, which is still a lot more than I am using currently.

Sidenote: I am aware that the two new tags are obsolete considering both are already contained by the plain searches for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) but the problem will present itself then the next time I add a tag.

Comment: That's a **lot** of tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real-time notifications for tagged questions only work for single tags. Your query has to be comprised only of tags that are combined with the *or* operator. In your 22 tags example, the issue lies in the [code-generation](/questions/tagged/code-generation)[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [code-generation](/questions/tagged/code-generation)[.net](/questions/tagged/.net) combinations. If you use [code-generation](/questions/tagged/code-generation) or [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [code-generation](/questions/tagged/code-generation) or [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) [(example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+asp.net+or+asp.net-mvc+or+asp.net-mvc-4+or+java+or+linq+or+design-patterns+or+android+or+unit-testing+or+architecture+or+design+or+oop+or+software-engineering+or+log4net+or+algorithm+or+wpf+or+linqpad+or+visual-studio+or+visual-studio-2012+or+resharper+or+code-generation+or+c%23+or+code-generation+or+.net?sort=newest&pageSize=15), you still get updates, even for 22 tags.

[image]

Comment: Cheers, that clarifies it. What is the reasoning behind this restriction?

Comment: It's simple to check if a question is tagged with a specific tag. It's not that simple to check against an entire tag expression.