# Available length of search inputs is different between top bar and search page

Tags: bug, design, search, top-bar

The top bar length for search query is 240 symbols, but for the search input on the search page the length is limited to 140 symbols. This leads to [weird behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222), when a can only delete the characters in page specific search input, but unable to change one symbol to another if the final length is more then 140 symbols.

> [image: search length]

There is also an issue with text oveflow on Search Results that goes through the Hot Network Questions section.

Could you please set the length limit equal for both inputs.

Comment: Some of this was already reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187508/323179).