# Syntax shortcut for multi-tag search

Tags: feature-request, tag-search

Suppose I want all questions tagged with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [unit-testing](/questions/tagged/unit-testing) and [testdoublejs](/questions/tagged/testdoublejs).

Current search query would be:

```
is:question [javascript] [unit-testing] [testdoublejs]
```

With terser tag syntax:

```
is:question [javascript unit-testing testdoublejs]
```

I think this could also help when we don't want certain tags.

Suppose I want all the questions tagged with [unit-testing](/questions/tagged/unit-testing) and [test-double](/questions/tagged/test-double) but not tagged with [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) or [php](/questions/tagged/php).

Current search query would be:

```
is:question [unit-testing] [test-double] -[kotlin] -[php]
```

With terser tag syntax:

```
is:question [unit-testing test-double] -[kotlin php]
```

Why?

I'm not claiming that this suggestion is a significant improvement over the existing search query syntax. Admittedly this only removes a couple of square brackets.

But I think it is important to declutter the syntax as much as possible so that we're left with just the bare minimum to accomplish our tasks.

A good search syntax is a powerful productivity tool.

Comment: And why would this be useful, or improve performance? Please make an argumented case for your request.

Comment: I'm not saying it will improve performance whatsoever. As for the usefulness of it I will leave it to the community to decide with their votes ;) — Although I would have thought that a shorter way of expressing the same thing (without compromising on clarity) would be considered a good feature of any search syntax.

Comment: NP - what's important to note is that if *we* do not understand the reasoning behind something, the company will *definitely* not do it. Have you checked the number of pending but never actioned requests lately? :)

Comment: Can you make it clearer in your question if it is a syntactical change only or if it enables new functionality? E.g., is "multi-tag negative search" already possible to that extend (more than one tag for the negative search?)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)

Comment: better now indeed :) I guess you can also mention that the search is actually limited in number of characters (but please do fact check that it is not the number of tags at the same time, I am not sure about the details) - when doing burnination requests on tags, many tend to run into issues when a lot of tags need to be excluded - so some reduction in characters would be nice

Comment: Ah, yes, self-fact-checked: [140 and 240 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324000/786798) - this is where any reduction in characters needed for input might really help